# Applicability of birthday attack to AES brute force

Tags: aes, brute-force-attack, birthday-attack

Is the following snippet from a recently published cryptography book correct?

EDIT: Expand the snippet from the book to make the context (symmetric key search) more clear.

> You can apply this to other cryptographic issues as well. Let's return to the DES algorithm.  Recall that it has 72,057,594,037,927,936 possible keys. To guarantee that you find the correct key, you may need to check all 72,057,594,037,927,936 possibilities.  However, if all you are seeking is a greater than 50 percent chance of finding the right key, you can try $1.774 \sqrt{72,057,594,037,927,936}$ possible keys -- only 476,204,499 possible keys. This is far more manageable.  In fact, again referring to our earlier scenario with DES, if you can attempt 1 million keys per second, you have a 50 percent chance of finding the right key in 7.9 minutes.  Although 1 million keys per second is beyond the capability of your standard personal computer, it is well within the capabilities of supercomputers or even computing clusters.
>
> The birthday paradox is one reason why larger key sizes are necessary
> for security.  If we move our attention from DES to an AES 128-bit
> key, there are approximately $3.402 * 10^{38}$ possible keys.  Applying
> the birthday paradox gives us $1.774 * \sqrt{3.402 * 10^{38}}$, or
> 32,724,523,986,760,744,567 keys that need to be attempted to have a 50
> percent chance of finding a match.  This number is large enough that
> it is computationally infeasible to break it through brute-force
> methods, even with the birthday paradox.

Comment: To get 50 percent chance of finding the right key, you need to try half the key space, not square root of key space?  Birthday attack would apply to hash collisions, not AES brute force?

Comment: Yes, a birthday attack scenario comes when a user generates *many* keys, and an attacker need only collide with one at random.

Comment: @otus Sure, it's on page 324 of this book:  [Modern Cryptography](http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Cryptography-Mathematics-Encryption-Information/dp/1259588084/)

Comment: Usually this kind of statement is only true if you have a significant amount of ciphertext (in this case created by multiple keys). That would mean you would also require a very large lookup table in memory. It would not work for just any attack vector.

Comment: It's very upsetting to see such horrible errors in a textbook...

Comment: @YehudaLindell: You are apparently confused by the volume of past discussions (some revised/deleted), I suppose. The birthday solution is the correct solution, see the discussions between fgrieu and me below.

Comment: @Mok-KongShen I don't agree. Birthday is not relevant at all. The reason is that there is a SINGLE key that I need to fine. If I try $\sqrt{n}$ keys then the chance that I find the correct one is $1/\sqrt{n}$. Birthday doesn't help at all.

Comment: @YehudaLindell: If I understand fgrieu's answer correctly, the chance is 0.5 if one tries a number of keys equal to that claimed in the book.

Comment: @Mok-KongShen The answer by fgrieu says explicitly that the birthday bound is irrelevant. In addition, and irrespective of this fact, he explains that the constant given for the birthday bound is incorrect (where it is relevant, which is not in this case). This claim in the book is COMPLETELY WRONG!

Comment: @YehudaLindell:  Apparently the book's author is perpetuating this misinformation on social media as well:  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/apple-vs-fbi-math-behind-story-chuck-easttom

Comment: @YehudaLindell: Many thanks. I was completely wrong as well in my thinking during the past couple of days. It's a big shame of mine.

Comment: @ThomasByrd Thanks for the LinkedIn link; I had to make a comment there...

Comment: @Mok-KongShen There is no shame in learning, ever! In Hebrew there is a saying that "a shy person does not learn". It is always OK to ask and learn, and a shy person who doesn't ask a seemingly stupid question will not learn.

Comment: @YehudaLindell:  Hopefully that will put the matter to rest, although I'm not so sure. In any case, your book co-authored with J. Katz is the one I usually refer to for anything important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The citation as [now](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/33149/4) expanded is clearly in the context of key search for a cipher, and grossly wrong, including time estimate to find a DES key with odds 50% with 1 million keys tested per second (that is over 11 centuries where 7.9 minutes is stated). In other contexts, the explanation could be right except for a moderate factor erring straight on the unsafe side, or vaguely related to a relevant phenomenon. In all cases, that's wrong; as well as the estimate of key test rate: one million DES keys per second on a consumer desktop CPU was already [feasible circa 1997](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dkindred/des/bitslice.html).

As pointed in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/33149/555#comment77238_33149) by the question's author, in the context of key search we need to search half of the key space to find a particular key with odds 50% (baring equivalent keys, and shortcuts to search). The birthday bound is irrelevant. After we searched the number of keys indicated in the citation ($1.774\sqrt n$ where $n$ is the size of the keyspace), our odds of having found the right key (assumed randomly chosen and initially unknown) is the ratio of the number of (distinct) keys tested, to the size of the keyspace; and that's in the order of $1.774/\sqrt n$, which is negligibly small, rather than 50% as stated.

The multiplicative constant for the birthday bound should be $\sqrt{\log4}\approx1.1774$ where the citation gives $1.774$, and uses it, making even the leftmost digit of both birthday bounds stated wrong, and erring on the unsafe side; see final note. Except for that, the explanation would have been right if the issue had been to guard against finding collisions for a one-way function such as $H:\{0,1\}^{128}\to\{0,1\}^{128};\; H(K)=\operatorname{AES-128}_K(0)$.

If we consider the security of a block cipher such as DES or AES in [CBC mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29), it is correct to invoke the birthday bound for collisions over the block size space; and for AES-128 this is the same as the key space, which makes the order of magnitude of the numbers in the second half of the citation relevant; however in that context the explanation does not justify *"why larger key sizes are necessary"*; only why larger block sizes are necessary.

As a practical illustration of the relevance of the birthday bound for CBC mode, consider a 40 GiB file, that is suspected to be the result of enciphering with 3DES in CBC mode a movie file directly extracted from a Blu-ray disk (perhaps with a little random added at the end of the file to hide the exact length of the original). The encrypted file is large enough that with odds better than 50%, two enciphered 64-bit blocks are identical. This implies that the eXclusive-OR of the two corresponding blocks in the original is equal to the eXclusive-OR of the preceding blocks in the encrypted file. That observation makes it feasible to demonstrate beyond reasonable doubt the nature of the encrypted file if the original is available, even if we have to decide among thousands of potential originals.

---

Note: The actual birthday bound for 56-bit (resp. 64-bit and 128-bit) values is 316,058,597 (resp. 5,056,937,541 and 21,719,381,355,163,562,492). That's applying David Brink: [*A (Probably) Exact Solution to the Birthday Problem*](http://www.davidbrink.dk/Birthday%20Problem.pdf) (in [The Ramanujan Journal, June 2012, Volume 28, Issue 2, pp 223-238](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-011-9343-9)), conjecturing that the number of uniformly chosen values among $n\ge1$ at which odds of collision reaches 50% is
$$\left\lceil\sqrt{n\log4}+{3-\log4\over6}+{9-\log^2 4\over72\sqrt{n\log4}}-{\log^2 4\over270n}\right\rceil$$
which in cryptography we tend to approximate with $1.1774\sqrt n$ or just $\sqrt n$, with both erring somewhat on the safe side from the legitimate user's perspective.

Comment: Does your 2nd paragraph claim that "we need to search half of the key space to find a given key with odds 50%"? If yes, I have a problem with my logic: Following the birthday problem,  keep generating randomly keys, test them for correctness and  independent of result put them into a room, until the number of keys there achieves the collision estimate. Now consider the right key enters that room. Isn't it that with a 50% chance it will find that there is an already existing copy of it? If so, what 's wrong with the other argument of needing trying keys of a number of half of the key space?

Comment: @fgrieu: Ok. But, if the number of keys already in the room is twice the collision estimate, would my argument be ok?

Comment: @fgrieu: Perhaps I yet misunderstood you. I meant that with key number of twice the collision estimate one highly probably ensures that all the keys in the room would contain distinct keys of a number  equal to that estimate (which was the condition not satisfied in my first comment according to your original critique).

Comment: @fgrieu: Would that imply that there might  be other estimates relevant for crypto that are similarly affected?

Comment: @Mok-Kong Shen: I hope to have addressed your first 3 comments in the expanded second paragraph of the answer (noting that in this, one can replace 1.774 by any fixed small constant, including 1.2 for a better estimate of the birthday bound, or twice that in order to be almost certain that the number of distinct keys is above the birthday bound).

Comment: @fgrieu: Yes, many thanks for that. I was subsequently thinking that very probably some other estimates should be similarly reviewed and perhaps someone in our community may eventually have the opportunity to call attention to that to a larger circle of people.

Comment: @Mok-Kong Shen I think you are making the same logical mistake as the author of the book.  As the accepted answer by fgrieu explains, the birthday bound does not apply when you start talking about finding collisions with "the right key".  It applies to the question:  Given n randomly chosen keys, what is the probability that there is a duplicate?  Note that this does not place any additional constraints on this duplicate, such as that it should be "the right key".  Once you specify such a constraint, the birthday bound no longer applies.

Comment: @fgrieu: Could you please say what's your opinion on Thomas Byrd's comment?

Comment: @Mok-Kong Shen: I fully agree with that part of Thomas Byrd's answer starting after the first comma. For the rest I can't read minds.

Comment: @fgrieu: I like to say that in the original version of your answer to the thread you mentioned sort of alternative viewpoints, one of which is the IMHO common saying that bruteforcing a block cipher needs n/2 trials in order to have 0.5 chance of success. (Note: "bruteforcing" is not further qualified with additional attributes.) But this common saying is blatantly a mistake due to the math known as the birthday problem. Further, the partyroom popularly used is a special case to render surprise to common people, so my use of it to argue for the general case [to be continued for space below]

Comment: [continued from above] is "redundant" and hence no good. Further, you critisized my description with the partyroom on the ground  that with a number of keys in the room equal to the collision estimate there could be identical keys and hence my description is not valid. But that critique is invalid and my later rescue employing twice the collision estimate is "unnecessary". This is because the math underlying the birthday problem permits identical items from the outset. E.g. HAC p.53 illustrates the problem with an urn of balls "with replacement". So IMHO we had actually "Much Ado for Nothing".

Comment: @fgrieu: [Addendum:] Since at the time of my earlier comment beginning with "Yes, many ..." I was yet confused by our discussions, i.e. not sure of whether the birthday solution is the long very well known correct solution, thus actually needing no discussions at all in this thread, I posted subsequently something to another group (in my sense of calling "attention to a larger circle of people" as indicated in that comment) and that post was (deservedly!) down-voted.

Comment: @fgrieu: I have to sincerely ask your pardon for not having carefully read your writing in your main post above. That I have only now noticed that the birthday estimate is irrelevant to the chance of finding the key is a big shame of mine.

Comment: To be fair the author uses `1.174 √n` just a paragraph above, so it must have been a typo